# How to mock __version__ in Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

In my `release_exporter/version.py` I have `__version__ = '1.0.6'` and I want to mock its `stdout`. `check_version()` prints out the latest version to the `stdout`.

I did mock `stdout` by doing

```
@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
def assert_stdout_1(self, n, expected_output, mock_stdout):
    request = check_version()
    self.assertIn(expected_output, mock_stdout.getvalue())
```

Which works fine.

I tried doing something like this to mock the version number:

```
def test_check_version_pass(self):
    version.__version__ = '1'

    self.assert_stdout_1('', 'New version')
```

I know this is wrong because I am not mocking it (though this works fine). Then I tried doing

```
@patch.object(version.__version__, 'version.__version__', return_value='1')
def test_check_version_pass(self):

    self.assert_stdout_1('', 'New version')
```

But I get an error as `AttributeError: 1.0.6 does not have the attribute 'version.__version__'`. I also tried using `@patch('release_exporter.version.__version__', return_value='1')` but I get an error as `TypeError: test_check_version_pass() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Help!

Comment: Maybe `@patch.object(version, '__version__', return_value='1')`?

Comment: @Sraw I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I got it. When using `@patch.object()` decorator always make sure that there is an argument to the method you are using this on. For example in my case (Thanks to [@Sraw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5588279/sraw)):

```
@patch.object(version, '__version__', return_value='1')
def test_check_version_pass(self, n):

    self.assert_stdout_1('', 'New version')
```

In this case, I have used an arbitrary argument `n`.